# Using PeerFinder inside local wired network for P2P communication between Windows 8.1 store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, p2p, windows-8.1

Is it possible to use PeerFinder for initiating connection between applications in different PCs inside intranet?

I tried ProximityCS (Windows 8.1) sample and PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes returns None for me. (Tested with Windows 8.1 Preview)

I have only found samples to connect using NFC or WifiDirect.
Is there any samples of using Infrastructure (TCP/IP) way of connecting?

Is it possible do this manually using Broadcast messages from Windows Store app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows store apps support multicast; from this you can build your discoverability solution.  There's a short video how-to about this on the Channel 9 site at http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Multicast-LAN-Discovery

To send a multicast message in Windows Runtime, just send it to a multicast address.  To receive, you just call [JoinMulticastGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.joinmulticastgroup.aspx) and you can start to receive.  To increase your code robustness, re-join when you learn about new networks; this will join the multicast group on newly available adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Peerfinder is part of the `Windows.Networking.Proxmity` namespace which, as you have mentioned, supports only NFC and WifiDirect for communication and data transfer between two applications in different PCs.

Have you tried using [StreamSocket](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931) so as to emulate a client-server like communication between two applications?

Comment: StreamSockets would be used for communication. But discovering other peers is the problem here... One option could be to build server for maintaining list of client IP adresses. Or just blindly scanning ip adresses. Ready made service like PeerFinder would just make life bit easier.

Comment: Ah thats true :). I think the problem you are talking about will be addressed when Intel comes out with its Common Connectivity Framework (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2k7IEra5-4). This framework can discover devices based on multiple attributes like : NFC,bluetooth etc.